# VueJS: Issue with using this keyword in arrow function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, arrow-functions

Recently working with VueJS - Vuex and I found the **this** keyword is confusing. Here the code in one of my components:

```
  props: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('storeJobNew', {
      factors: (state) => state.job['majors']
    })
  },
```

It's work fine, until I want to make it dynamic, so the **computed.factors** is now base on the **props.name** value.

```
  props: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('storeJobNew', {
      factors: (state) => state.job[this.name]
    })
  },
```

Now **computed.factors** is **undefined**. After a few hours of Googling, I found out that I shouldn't use arrow function here, and my code look like this:

```
  props: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('storeJobNew', {
      factors: function (state) { return state.job[this.name] }
    })
  },
```

So here the question:

1. Why **this** keyword in arrow function not working here? (I thought that the **this** keyword here should be the Vue instance that I was created)
2. Why I need to write **this.name** instead of **this.props.name** to access the value in props?

Comment: You must not ask two completely different not related question in one.

Comment: I thought that both of them related to the 'this' keyword. Well, I'll rework the first one to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to `Proxy` in any way. The `this` of the arrow function refers to the context in which the arrow function was created. So if you have something like this:

```
Vue.component('component', {
// ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState('storeJobNew', {
      factors: (state) => state.job[this.name]
    })
  }
// ...
}

console.dir(this)
```

The `this` of `this.name` is the same as the one of `console.dir(this)` because it would be identical to writing:

```
var factors = (state) => state.job[this.name]

Vue.component('component', {
// ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState('storeJobNew', {
      factors: factors
    })
  }
// ...
}

console.dir(this)
```

The context is the one of the closest enclosing function ion which the arrow function was created, or if there is none then the global context.

And to: `Why I need to write this.name instead of this.props.name to access the value in props?` that how it is defined by the Vue API. When accessing the values you should not need to distinguish between how why where defined.

Comment: So the closest context, in this case, is the window right? I have thought that it's the Vue instance.

Comment: @LêQuangBảo In this case yes. Before you call `Vue.component()` you create `'component'` and `{ computed: { ... factors: (state) => state.job[this.name] ... }`, so at the time of creation you are in the global context, then those two objects are passed to `Vue.component()`.